# is there a difference in time/space complexity between recursive and non-recursive merge sort algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, recursion, mergesort

I have implemented a merge sort algorithm using divide and conquer approach where an array is split into two sub arrays.

In my code i re-used insertion sort algorithm to sort the sub arrays in merge sort. Is this right approach or i have to use different sorting approach to sort the sub arrays in merge sort ?

As far as concerned with the understanding of merge sort algorithm, everything is clear but when coming to the implementation of merge sort, how does it happen to divide an array into n-sub arrays without using recursive strategy.

is recursive or non-recursive efficient way to implement merge sort ?

Below is my code snippet in github:
https://github.com/vamsikankipati/algorithms-in-java/blob/master/src/com/algorithms/sort/MergeSort.java

I have understood from implementation perspective that my code is wrong as i divided the array into only two sub arrays instead of n-sub arrays.

Any help needed to clearly understand merge sort in terms of algorithm implementation perspective.

Here is the code:

```java
package com.algorithms.sort;

public class MergeSort {

    public static int[] increasing(int[] arr) {
        int[] result = new int[arr.length];
        int q = arr.length / 2;
        System.out.println("q: " + q);
        int[] left = new int[q];
        int[] right = new int[q];
        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            left[i] = arr[i];
        }
        int k = 0;
        for (int j = q; j < arr.length; j++) {
            right[k] = arr[j];
            k += 1;
        }
        left = InsertionSort.increasing(left);
        right = InsertionSort.increasing(right);

        // Printing
        for (int e : left) {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        for (int e : right) {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int s = 0;
        while ((i < left.length) && (j < right.length)) {
            if (left[i] <= right[j]) {
                result[s] = left[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                result[s] = right[j];
                j++;
            }
            s++;
        }
        while (i < left.length) {
            result[s] = left[i];
            i++;
            s++;
        }
        while (j < right.length) {
            result[s] = right[j];
            j++;
            s++;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Main method to test an example integer array
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ar = { 18, 12, 11, 6, 55, 100 };
        int[] res = increasing(ar);
        for (int a : res) {
            System.out.print(a + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557894/non-recursive-merge-sort) question helps?

Comment: partially yes, but how do we implement merge sort without using recursion ? as per your link, it says that O(n lg n) is the time complexity for both recursive and non-recursive merge sort.

Comment: This you can easily get by a simple google search. Isn't it?

Comment: I suggest you search how to write recursion in non-recursive way and vice versa. That will give you the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More important than optimisation, you must first achieve correctness. There is a bug in the `increasing` static method: if the size of the array argument is not even, the `right` subarray is allocated with an incorrect size: `int[] right = new int[q];` should be

```
int[] right = new int[arr.length - q];
```

Furthermore, you should not try to split the array if it is too small.

Regarding optimisation, you should only fallback to `InsertionSort()` when the subarray size is below a threshold, somewhere between 16 and 128 elements. Careful benchmarking with different thresholds and a variety of distributions will help determine a good threshold for your system.

As currently implemented, your function has a time complexity of **O(N<sup>2</sup>)** because it defers to `InsertionSort` for all but the last merge phase. To reduce the complexity to **O(N.log(N))**, you must recurse on the subarrays until their size is below a fixed threshold.

Here is a modified version:

```java
package com.algorithms.sort;

public class MergeSort {

    public static int threshold = 32;

    public static int[] increasing(int[] arr) {
        if (arr.length <= threshold)
            return InsertionSort.increasing(arr);

        int len1 = arr.length / 2;
        int[] left = new int[len1];
        for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
            left[i] = arr[i];
        }
        int len2 = arr.length - len1;
        int[] right = new int[len2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len2; i++) {
            right[i] = arr[i + len1];
        }
        left = increasing(left);
        right = increasing(right);

        int[] result = new int[len1 + len2];
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int s = 0;
        while (i < len1 && j < len2) {
            if (left[i] <= right[j]) {
                result[s] = left[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                result[s] = right[j];
                j++;
            }
            s++;
        }
        while (i < len1) {
            result[s] = left[i];
            i++;
            s++;
        }
        while (j < len2) {
            result[s] = right[j];
            j++;
            s++;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Main method to test an example integer array
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ar = { 18, 12, 11, 6, 55, 100 };
        int[] res = increasing(ar);
        for (int a : res) {
            System.out.print(a + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both time complexity is O( n log n).

About space complexity, the implementation may vary on your data structure choice.
in recursive 
   if you choose array: 
       space complexity: N log N
   if you choose linked-list:
       space complexity is O(1)
in iterative:
   if you choose array: 
       space complexity: N
       ( based on your implementation it is O ( N log N) because you create a new sub-array in every dividing state, 
to reduce it to O(n) you should use one extra array as size of the original one, and indexes)
   if you choose linked-list:
       space complexity is O(1)

As you can see linked-list is best for sorting.
Beyond that recursive may consume more memory than expected based on programming language because of function frame creation.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Comment: *As you can see linked-list is best for sorting.* That's a pretty broad statement. If you're given an array and asked to sort it, it doesn't make sense to create a linked list. That would make memory O(n). Also, since you can't index into a linked list, you have to iterate over it to find the halfway point to split it into two. That's extra work. It also takes longer to follow a `next` pointer than it does to increment an array index. It's quite possible that the linked list sort has a higher constant and will be slower than the array sort.

Comment: Sounds efficient in terms of data structure choice while sorting. Anyway why would one choose linked-list over arrays ? Is there a use case where Linked list is preferred over arrays in any of the sorting algorithms ? I am not sure if there is any. did you see one ?