# identical result qsort vs std::sort

Tags: c++

Please excuse the brevity of the message.

I have an array of records. I want to sort it in descending order w.r.t. one of it's key. Records' key are not unique.

compare function of qsort:

```
int cmp(const record* rec1, const record* rec2) 
{
    return rec2->key - rec1->key;
}
```

compare function of std::sort:

```
bool operator()(const record& rec1, const record& rec2) 
{
    return rec1.key > rec2.key;
}
```

Will both the version give identical result? I am not sure if sort/qsort behave same way when keys are equal.

Comment: What is the definition of the `record` type?

Comment: example: struct s { char* name; int key};

Comment: result is not guarantied to be equal (due to equivalent items unspecified order), but both ranges will be sorted.

Comment: Yep, as @Jarod42 mentions, quicksort is not (generally) a [stable sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts).

Comment: I understand that it is not guaranteed. I am using gcc. Would you know the internal?

Comment: @user3689963 - the results will be different on equal keys depending on several potential differences between qsort and std::sort: what triggers a switch to heap sort and/or insertion sort; how pivot value is choosen; if a 2 way versus 3 way (the third partition would be keys == pivot key) is used, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Neither of these sorts are guaranteed to be [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts) sorts. Elements that compare equal may not appear in the same order using either sort.

There is also nothing in [alg.sort] guaranteeing that they use the same algorithm/implementation of that algorithm. In fact, since C++11 [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) is *guaranteed* to be O(n log n), whereas, despite its name [std::qsort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort) is not even guaranteed to be a Quick Sort, much less have any specific time complexity (Which means that [Bogosort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) is a conforming `qsort` implementation)

---

#### Edit

Since in the comments you specify that you're using GCC and are interested if perhaps that platform uses the same sort, the answer remains "no".

- [Which sorting algorithm is used in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7221257/27678) (for std::sort, it's "Introsort")

For `qsort`, it comes from whatever libc your version of GCC uses.

- [FreeBSD's qsort.c](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/lib/libc/stdlib/qsort.c) admittedly also appears to be an Introsort implementation, although the code is not identical and it's hard to say outright if they'd give you the same result.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such guarantee.

[`std::qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort):

> If `comp` indicates two elements as equivalent, their order is unspecified.

[`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

> The order of equal elements is not guaranteed to be preserved.

You need a stable sorting algorithm if the order of equal elements needs to be preserved. [`std::stable_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) is stable.

Alternatively just add more keys to sort by so that no elements compare equal.