# Natural mergesort a linked list

Tags: sorting, linked-list, mergesort

I have been looking for a **natural** mergesort implementation (**linked lists**) for a while now but had no luck.

[Merge Sort a Linked List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685/merge-sort-a-linked-list)

Here we have both, the recursive and the iterative implementation but I don't know how to turn this into a natural mergesort.

How do I check for the runs to get **O(n)** complexity in the best case? It does not have to be C/C++, can be any language or even Pseudocode.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pseudocode implementation on [Wikipedia](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Merge_sort#Natural_mergesort):

```
 # Original data is on the input tape; the other tapes are blank
 function mergesort(input_tape, output_tape, scratch_tape_C, scratch_tape_D)
     while any records remain on the input_tape
         while any records remain on the input_tape
             merge( input_tape, output_tape, scratch_tape_C)
             merge( input_tape, output_tape, scratch_tape_D)
         while any records remain on C or D
             merge( scratch_tape_C, scratch_tape_D, output_tape)
             merge( scratch_tape_C, scratch_tape_D, input_tape)

 # take the next sorted chunk from the input tapes, and merge into the single given output_tape.
 # tapes are scanned linearly.
 # tape[next] gives the record currently under the read head of that tape.
 # tape[current] gives the record previously under the read head of that tape.
 # (Generally both tape[current] and tape[previous] are buffered in RAM ...)
 function merge(left[], right[], output_tape[])
     do
        if left[current] ≤ right[current]
            append left[current] to output_tape
            read next record from left tape
        else
            append right[current] to output_tape
            read next record from right tape
    while left[current] < left[next] and right[current] < right[next]
    if left[current] < left[next]
        append current_left_record to output_tape
    if right[current] < right[next]
        append current_right_record to output_tape
    return
```

Comment: Thanks, it's not from Wikipedia.

It seems like this could work for linked lists but this design requires pass by reference or double pointers which are not available in my target language.

Still trying to work around this.

Comment: No, can't apply this logic to linked lists.

Comment: The pseudocode is either incomplete, I misinterpret it or just wrong. Can't get this to work on paper/theory either.

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt in F#. An implementation of regular merge sort for reference:

```
// Sorts a list containing elements of type T.  Takes a comparison
// function comp that takes two elements of type T and returns -1
// if the first element is less than the second, 0 if they are equal,
// and 1 if the first element is greater than the second.
let rec sort comp = function 
| []  -> []  // An empty list is sorted
| [x] -> [x] // A single element list is sorted
| xs  ->
    // Split the list in half, sort both halves,
    // and merge the sorted halves.
    let half = (List.length xs) / 2
    let left, right = split half xs
    merge comp (sort comp left) (sort comp right)
```

Now an attempt at the natural version. This will be O(n) in the best case, but the best case is when the input list is in reverse sorted order.

```
let rec sort' comp ls =

    // Define a helper function.  Streaks are stored in an accumulator.
    let rec helper accu = function
    | [] -> accu 
    | x::xs -> 
        match accu with
        // If we are not in a streak, start a new one
        | [] -> helper [x] xs 

        // If we are in a streak, check if x continues
        // the streak.
        | y::ys -> 
            if comp y x > 0 

            // x continues the streak so we add it to accu
            then helper (x::y::ys) xs

            // The streak is over. Merge the streak with the rest
            // of the list, which is sorted by calling our helper function on it.
            else merge comp accu (helper [x] xs)

    helper [] ls
```

A second attempt. This will also be O(n) in the best case, where the best case is now when the input list is already sorted. I negated the comparison function. The sorted list will be built up in reversed order so you need to reverse it at the end.

```
let rec sort'' comp ls =
    // Flip the comparison function
    let comp' = fun x y -> -1 * (comp x y)
    let rec helper accu = function
    | [] -> accu
    | x::xs -> 
        match accu with
        | [] -> helper [x] xs
        | y::ys -> 
            if comp' y x > 0 
            then helper (x::y::ys) xs
            else merge comp' accu (helper [x] xs)

    // The list is in reverse sorted order so reverse it.
    List.rev (helper [] ls)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the natural merge sort , but merge sort for linked list, I write like this:

> [Code in Java]

```
// Merge sort the linked list.
// From min to max.
// Time complexity = O(nlgn).
public static Node mergeSortLLFromMinToMax (Node head) {
    if (head == null || head.next == null) return head; // No need to sort.
    // Get the mid point of this linked list.
    Node prevSlower = head;
    Node slower = head;
    Node faster = head;
    while (faster != null && faster.next != null) {
        prevSlower = slower;
        slower = slower.next;
        faster = faster.next.next;
    }
    // Cut of the main linked list.
    prevSlower.next = null;

    // Do recursion.
    Node left = mergeSortLLFromMinToMax (head);
    Node right = mergeSortLLFromMinToMax (slower);

    // Merge the left and right part from min to max.
    Node currHead = new Node ();
    Node tempCurrHead = currHead;
    while (left != null && right != null) {
        if (left.data <= right.data) {
            // Add the elem of the left part into main linked list.
            tempCurrHead.next = left;
            left = left.next;
        } else {
            // Add the elem of the right part into main linked list.
            tempCurrHead.next = right;
            right = right.next;
        }
        tempCurrHead = tempCurrHead.next;
    }
    if (left != null) {
        // Add the remaining part of left part into main linked list.
        tempCurrHead.next = left;
        left = left.next;
        tempCurrHead = tempCurrHead.next;
    } else if (right != null) {
        // Add the remaining part of right part into main linked list.
        tempCurrHead.next = right;
        right = right.next;
        tempCurrHead = tempCurrHead.next;
    }

    return currHead.next;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My very raw implementation of the algorithm using C#

```
public static class LinkedListSort
{
    public static DataStructures.Linear.LinkedListNode<T> Sort<T>(DataStructures.Linear.LinkedListNode<T> firstNode) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        if (firstNode == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        if (firstNode.Next == null)
            return firstNode;

        var head = firstNode;
        var leftNode = head;
        int iterNum = 0;

        while (leftNode != null)
        {
            //Let's start again from the begining
            leftNode = head;
            iterNum = 0;
            DataStructures.Linear.LinkedListNode<T> tailNode = null;

            while (leftNode != null)
            {
                //Let's get the left sublist

                //Let's find the node which devides sublist into two ordered sublists
                var sentinelNode = GetSentinelNode(leftNode);
                var rightNode = sentinelNode.Next;

                //If the right node is null it means that we don't have two sublist and the left sublist is ordered already
                //so we just add the rest sublist to the tail
                if (rightNode == null)
                {
                    if (tailNode == null)
                        break;
                    tailNode.Next = leftNode;
                    break;
                }

                sentinelNode.Next = null;

                //Let's find the node where the right sublist ends
                sentinelNode = GetSentinelNode(rightNode);
                var restNode = sentinelNode.Next;
                sentinelNode.Next = null;

                DataStructures.Linear.LinkedListNode<T> newTailNode = null;

                //Merging of two ordered sublists   
                var mergedList = Merge(leftNode, rightNode, ref newTailNode);
                //If we're at the beginning of the list the head of the merged sublist becomes the head of the list
                if (iterNum == 0)                   
                    head = mergedList;                  
                else //add the                  
                    tailNode.Next = mergedList;                     

                tailNode = newTailNode;
                leftNode = restNode;
                iterNum++;
            }
            if (iterNum == 0)
                break;
        }
        return head;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Merges two ordered sublists   
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="aNode">Left part of sublist</param>
    /// <param name="bNode">Right part of sublist</param>
    /// <param name="tailNode">Tail node of the merged list</param>
    /// <returns>The result of merging</returns>
    private static DataStructures.Linear.LinkedListNode<T> Merge<T>(DataStructures.Linear.LinkedListNode<T> leftNode,                                                                       
                                                                    DataStructures.Linear.LinkedListNode<T> rightNode,
                                                                    ref DataStructures.Linear.LinkedListNode<T> tailNode) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        var dummyHead = new DataStructures.Linear.LinkedListNode<T>();
        var curNode = dummyHead;

        while (leftNode != null || rightNode != null)
        {
            if (rightNode == null)
            {
                curNode.Next = leftNode;
                leftNode = leftNode.Next;
            }
            else if (leftNode == null)
            {
                curNode.Next = rightNode;
                rightNode = rightNode.Next;
            }
            else if (leftNode.Value.CompareTo(rightNode.Value) <= 0)
            {
                curNode.Next = leftNode;
                leftNode = leftNode.Next;
            }
            else
            {
                curNode.Next = rightNode;
                rightNode = rightNode.Next;
            }
            curNode = curNode.Next;
        }
        tailNode = curNode;
        return dummyHead.Next;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the sentinel node
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="firstNode"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static DataStructures.Linear.LinkedListNode<T> GetSentinelNode<T>(DataStructures.Linear.LinkedListNode<T> firstNode) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        var curNode = firstNode;

        while (curNode != null && curNode.Next != null && curNode.Value.CompareTo(curNode.Next.Value) <= 0)             
            curNode = curNode.Next;

        return curNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where this identifies runs in the input data, as required by the *natural* part of the question and the O(n) best-case runtime. Can you enlighten me?

Comment: @MarkRansom Natural merge sort assumes that we exploit naturally occurring sorted sequences. In my implementation I exploit this case. The best-case O(n) we have when all elements of the input data are ordered. My edited implementation also exploits this case.