# Making an efficient algorithm for sorting with a pointer

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list

Consider a simple struct:

```
struct Node{
 int val;
 Node *next;
 Node *freeNode;
};
```

Now I have to sort a given linked list only using freeNode and the method has to be efficient. I can't make another list and use some kind of sorted-insert there. Nor can use *genome or bubble sort*. The pointer `freeNode` of any elem in the list can be pointing to any elem in the list.

Now I have come up with two ideas:

1. Use freeNode to make a doubly Linked List.

   And do pair comparing, i.e. compare the ith elem with the (i+1)th elem. When I find that two elements need to be swapped, I swap them and then again start from the head of the List.

   This algorithm would be more than O(n) (not sure just guessing). It will take much time.
2. Another method is that my freeNode points to elem that is smaller than it.

   E.g. if I have `30->6->14->56>Tail`, then

   ```
   56->freeNode->14
   30->freeNode->14
   14->freeNode->6
   6->freeNode->NULL.
   ```

   But again, this doesn't help much, because when I insert `45 or 20` I would have to re-arrange my `freeNode` pointer. And, again, it would not be a very efficient method.

Any suggestions on this? How to use `freeNode` to implement a better and efficient method for sorting. Pseudo-code would work, and I'd actually prefer that over real code.

**EDIT: You can't use arrays, vectors or anything else. Just the `freeNode` pointer. Use it in any way you want. Keep it NULL or have it point to elements of your choice.**

Comment: Please, specify, how do you want to sort the list.
You can simply use some conventional method of sorting if you map the list to  some kind of vector.

Comment: Have you tried mergesort, quicksort or any other standard sorting method?

Comment: Not Familiar with any one,. can you explain ???/

Comment: @V-X No vectors. Nothing else.just This FreeNode pointer. You can not use any thing else.

Comment: Given the constraints in your last edit, this sounds like a homework question. Is it?

Comment: [Mergesort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685/merge-sort-a-linked-list) the list, and there are only about a thousand samples implementations that do it, one linked with this comment. It is O(NlogN) and plenty-efficient for space needs. It requires no additional pointers (except the temp pointers in the recursive algorithm) and in fact, you don't need the `freeNode` pointer for it  either (though using it for a `prev` pointer would make the final algorithm significantly more straight-forward to implement).

Comment: @roger_rowland constraints mean you want to implement that way, more efficiently. See if things work that way as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a binary tree.  Use next as your right child pointer and freeNode as your left child pointer.
Make the first of the nodes you should sort your root.
Then, take the rest of your nodes and "insert" them in your new binary tree.

Edit:  Like this:

Your typedef:

```
typedef struct Node{
 int val;
 struct Node *next;
 struct Node *freeNode;
} NodeT;
```

Some defines to make this code easier to read:

```
// Conversions to make this code easier to read.
#define pRight freeNode
#define pLeft  next
```

Recursive binary tree insertion:

```
static void BinTreeInsert( NodeT *pRootNode, NodeT *pChildNode );
```

Edit 2: solution removed when made apparent that this was homework. Figure out out dude!

This solution would be O(n log n) best / average case but O(n2) worst case... If the incoming list is already sorted.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_sort#section_1

Comment: @DeadCoder, Read the Wikipedia on it. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_sort#section_1