# Complexity and explanation of a part of a C program which uses data structures

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

**We have the following piece of a C program.I want to understand what this part of code does and its complexity.**

```
void   sortLike          (node* p) 
        node* q;
        node* min;
        node *head = (struct node*) malloc (sizeof (struct node));
        head->next = L;
        p = head;
```

// We have to sort the list,obviously.We have the variable p and q which are pointer to node variables.We have determined the size of the head node.I dont understand what **node* min** and **head->next = L;** means.

```
        while (p->next->next!=NULL)
        {
            min = p;
            q = p->next;
            while (q->next!=NULL)
            {
                if (min->next->like < q->next->like)
                    min = q;
                q = q->next;
```

What does this block of code do?

```
}
                node* a = p->next;
                p->next = min->next;
                min->next = a;
                node* b = a->next;
                a->next = p->next->next;
                p->next->next = b;
                p = p->next;
            }
            L = head->next;
        }
```

What about this one?

**Question : What kind of sorting algorithm is this? I would guess it's selection sort.Whats its complexity?Can we turn this into a merge sort algorithm?**

Comment: What is L? Can you please show me it's declaration (which might be done in the earlier part of the program)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void   sortLike          (node* p) 
        node* q;
        node* min;
        node *head = (struct node*) malloc (sizeof (struct node));
        head->next = L;
        p = head;
```

This allocates a [sentinel node](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node) and inserts it at the beginning of the list. I probably would have allocated it on the stack (actually, I probably would have used pointers to pointers throughout, but that's off-topic). It also allocates some variables whose purpose is as yet unclear.

---

```
while (p->next->next!=NULL)
{
    min = p;
    q = p->next;
    while (q->next!=NULL)
    {
        if (min->next->like < q->next->like)
            min = q;
        q = q->next;
```

This part looks for the node having the minimum value of `->like`, breaking ties in favor of later nodes (so this sort isn't stable). The meanings of `p` and `min` are a little funny: they point to the node before the beginning of the current sublist and the node before the minimum respectively. This is so that we can splice (next chunk; also explains why we needed the sentinel).

---

```
        node* a = p->next;
        p->next = min->next;
        min->next = a;
        node* b = a->next;
        a->next = p->next->next;
        p->next->next = b;
        p = p->next;
    }
    L = head->next;
}
```

This chunk moves `min->next` to the beginning of the list and moves `p` forward one, completing an implementation of selection sort for linked lists.

Comment: Whats the complexity? :) is it O(n^2)?

Comment: Best answer.How can I 'convert' this to mergesort? So  I  reduce the complexity I mean :)

Comment: @user3543012 Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685/merge-sort-a-linked-list

Comment: I will try to copy paste this code.http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/algorithms/listsort.c
Thanks.