# How to sort link list in correct way C

Tags: c, list

I try to sort linked list by field year, but my code incorrect. I have such list and function to sort linked list:

```
struct sputnik {
char nazvanie[30];
char nazvanie_main[30];
int year;
float d;
int period;
struct sputnik *next;
};

int f_sort (struct sputnik **head,int*count) {
struct sputnik *prev,*current,*buffer, *buf;
int i;
current=*head;

for (i=0;i<*count;i++) {
while (current!=NULL){
prev=current;
buf=current->next;
if (prev->year>buf->year){
buffer=buf->next;
buf->next=prev->next;
prev->next=buffer;
current=prev->next;

}
else{
current=buf->next;
}
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Count in my code is amoumt of elements in my list.

Comment: Please re-write this in the form of a question. Show us what you've tried so far, and suggest what you think is broken.

Comment: You are dereferencing `buf` which came from `buf=current->next;` without checking `if (buf != NULL)`.

Comment: Also your function `f_sort()` is taking two parameters by reference, but it changes neither of them. That's not a mistake (unless you intended to alter `head` in the sort), just redundancy.

Comment: No indentation, no data, no debugging, no error details.  Par for the course, so downvote/closevote.

Answer (score -1):

You need to update the head of the list as needed and reset current back to the head of the list after the for(i = 0 ...) loop. This would be easier if you used a pointer to pointer to current instead of "prev". For example:

```
struct sputnik **ppcurrent;
    /* ... */
    for(i=0 ...
        ppcurrent = head;
        while(NULL != *ppcurrent && NULL != (*ppcurrent)->next){
            /* ... if swap */
                *ppcurrent = ... ;  /* update head or a next pointer */
            /* ... */
            ppcurrent = &((*ppcurrent)->next); /* advance ppcurrent */
```

There better ways to sort a list, but see if you can get your current version to work first.

---

For others reading this, better ways:

bottom up merge sort for linked list:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists

Example C code:

[Merge Sort a Linked List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685/merge-sort-a-linked-list/33987943#33987943)

In most cases, since sequential access of scattered nodes involves random access of memory, which is not cache friendly, it's usually faster to copy the list to an array, sort the array, then create a sorted list from the array. This is what Java does in collections.sort() for native linked list.

Comment: Going down for not listing the `better ways to sort a list`.

Comment: @Deanie -  the plan was to list the better ways after the OP got the question's version of code to work. The OP never responded and never updated the question. I've updated my answer for others reading this.