# Why doesn't this merge-sort function cause an infinite loop?

Tags: java, sorting, merge, mergesort

I'm working on a project that requires me to implement merge-sort on a linked list and I am using the code from this post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685/merge-sort-a-linked-list) to help me. Can someone explain to why on line 6, when I call `return merge(merge_sort(head),merge_sort(sHalf));` the method `merge_sort(head)` inside of it, which contains the same head pointer doesn't cause an infinite loop? It seems to me that it is starting all over again with the same head pointer.

```
public Node merge_sort(Node head) {
    if(head == null || head.next == null) { return head; }
    Node middle = getMiddle(head);      //get the middle of the list
    Node sHalf = middle.next; middle.next = null;   //split the list into two               halfs

    return merge(merge_sort(head),merge_sort(sHalf));  //recurse on that
}

//Merge subroutine to merge two sorted lists
public Node merge(Node a, Node b) {
    Node dummyHead, curr; dummyHead = new Node(); curr = dummyHead;
    while(a !=null && b!= null) {
        if(a.info <= b.info) { curr.next = a; a = a.next; }
        else { curr.next = b; b = b.next; }
        curr = curr.next;
    }
    curr.next = (a == null) ? b : a;
    return dummyHead.next;
}

//Finding the middle element of the list for splitting
public Node getMiddle(Node head) {
    if(head == null) { return head; }
    Node slow, fast; slow = fast = head;
    while(fast.next != null && fast.next.next != null) {
        slow = slow.next; fast = fast.next.next;
    }
    return slow;
}
```

Comment: Alternate bottom up method for sorting link lists, simple and faster than scanning lists to split them.  Wiki has an example similar to what is used in std::list::sort. It uses the same merge function as what you have in your code.
[bottom merge sort for lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the previous line:

```
Node sHalf = middle.next; middle.next = null;
```

Specifically, the `middle.next = null;` part.

Understand that even though the head pointer is the same, **we are splitting the list into half**, using `middle.next = null`. So, in the next recursive call, it's only half the linked list which was sent originally.

And at one point, it will reach `head.next == null` condition.