# Sorting a queue in O(n log n) using at most 2 queue

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

We were tasked to sort a queue in O(n log n) using basic functions such as enqueue, dequeue, peek, empty only. Additionally, we may use another queue to help us. No other data structures are allowed.

Having trouble coming up with a solution as I feel like this is possibly an modification of a divide-and-conquer problem but I am unable to come up with a solution using the 4 basic functions.

Is it possible to receive some hints to solve this problem?

Comment: By enqueue and dequeue you mean basic push and pop?

Comment: Yup, enqueue == push and dequeue == pop

Comment: More precisely, enqueuing will happen from the bottom and dequeuing from the top?

Comment: Yup. For example a queue, q,  with elements {1, 2, 3, 4}.

q.push(5), elements = {1, 2, 3, 4 ,5}
q.pop(), elements = {2, 3, 4, 5}

Comment: You can do a merge sort using queues.

Comment: When you say 4 basic functions, are we allowed only those 4? I presume you may need to clarify that once again with the guy who gave this question.

Comment: Since a queue is implementable as a singly linked list that keeps a reference to its tail, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685/merge-sort-a-linked-list) may be able to help you out, or one of the other 'Merge sort a linked list' questions in other languages.

Comment: Are any variables allowed other than the 2 queues?

Comment: Are you limiting things to one additional queue, or would two be allowed? If the queues are linked lists, then it's only a constant amount of additional storage.

Answer (score 10):

Given queue A full and queue B empty, if A consists of sorted groups of *w* elements, then you can merge them in pairs to produce sorted groups of *2w* elements as follows:

1. While(A.length - B.length > w), pull w elements out of A and put them in B.  A and B will then both consist of sorted groups of *w* elements, plus some left over.
2. repeatedly pull w elements from both A and B, merging them onto the back of A to create sorted groups of *2w* elements.  Stop when all the elements have been processed (be careful not to pull elements from A that you already processed. You'll need to remember its original size).  A will then consist of of sorted *2w* groups, and B will be empty again.

Repeat the above procedure with *w=1* (groups of 1 are always sorted), then *w=2*, *w=4* ... *w=2<sup>n</sup>*, etc. until the whole queue is sorted.

Comment: this is a nice way to think of merge sort in general