# merge sort linkedlist - stackoverflow error

Tags: recursion, linked-list, mergesort

I am trying to solve leetcode-148 (https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-list/) i.e. sort given LinkedList, but am getting a stackoverflow error. so far I have tried dry running but am not seeing where the issue could occur.. the base condition of the recursion seems to be right but looks like I am missing something if someone sees what I am not seeing..

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode() {}
 *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode sortList(ListNode head) {
        if (head==null || head.next==null) return head;

        ListNode follow = new ListNode(0);
        follow.next=head;
        ListNode fast = head;
        ListNode slow = head;
        
        // Find the mid-point of the list
        while (fast.next!=null && fast.next.next!=null) {
            slow=slow.next;
            fast=fast.next.next;
            follow=follow.next;
        }

        // Split the list
        follow.next = null;
        
        // Sort each half
        ListNode first = sortList(head);
        ListNode second = sortList(slow);
        
        // Merge
        return merge(first, second);
    }
    
    private ListNode merge(ListNode first, ListNode second) {
        if (first==null) return second;
        if (second==null) return first;
        
        ListNode result = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode head = result;
        
        while (first!=null && second!=null) {
            if (first.val<second.val) {
                result.next = first;
            } else {
                result.next = second;
            }
            
            result=result.next;
        }
        
        if (first!=null) {
            result.next = first;
            result=result.next;
        }
        
        if (second!=null) {
            result.next = second;
            result=result.next;
        }
        
        return head.next;
    }
}
```

Here's the error

```
WARNING: A command line option has enabled the Security Manager
WARNING: The Security Manager is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
java.lang.StackOverflowError
  at line 31, Solution.sortList
  at line 31, Solution.sortList
  at line 31, Solution.sortList
  at line 31, Solution.sortList
  at line 31, Solution.sortList
```

Comment: *"sort 2 given LinkedLists"*: the code challenge is about sorting 1 linked list.

Comment: Technically, a top down merge sort for linked list fails the stated goal of O(1) space, since O(log(n)) space is used for the stack. A [bottom up merge sort for linked lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685/33987943#33987943) meets the goals, and is also faster for a large list with scattered nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues:

- When `sortList` is called with a list that has 2 nodes, then after the first loop (which makes no iterations), `slow` will be equal to `head`, and `follow.next = null` will just mutate the dummy node that was prepended before the `head` node. So essentially the linked list wasn't split, and the recursive call is on the *same* list, leading to infinite recursion. Solve this by changing the `while` condition so at least one iteration will be made. Also, you can do this without a third reference (`follow`).
- In `merge`, the `first` and `second` references do not move forward, so the loop will be infinite.

Here is corrected code:

```java
public ListNode sortList(ListNode head) {
    if (head == null || head.next == null) return head;

    ListNode fast = head.next;
    ListNode slow = head;
    
    // Find the mid-point of the list
    while (fast != null && fast.next != null) { // iterate at least once
        slow = slow.next;
        fast = fast.next.next;
    }

    // Split the list
    ListNode second = slow.next;
    slow.next = null;
    
    // Sort each half
    head = sortList(head);
    second = sortList(second);
    
    // Merge
    return merge(head, second);
}

private ListNode merge(ListNode first, ListNode second) {
    ListNode result = new ListNode(0);
    ListNode head = result;
    
    while (first != null && second != null) {
        if (first.val < second.val) {
            result.next = first;
            first = first.next; // move forward
        } else {
            result.next = second;
            second = second.next;
        }            
        result = result.next;
    }
    if (first != null) {
        result.next = first;
        result = result.next;
    }
    if (second != null) {
        result.next = second;
        result = result.next;
    }
    return head.next;
}
```

Comment: Excellent!! Thank you!! That makes it crystal clear! Ya I missed the merge pointer increment part, my bad (pretty sure I had that coded but somehow ended up messing it up). The root cause makes perfect sense. You are amazing! :)