# Ascending sorting of a linked list by node's int value in C

Tags: c, sorting, struct, linked-list

The first approach to linked lists ever. As stated in the title, I'm trying to get a function that sorts a linked list's nodes by their `int` value (`val`).
But as the function gets called the program leaves me hanging.

Given my simple node struct:

```c
struct node {
    int val;
    struct node* next;
};
```

This is the function that I hoped would do it:

```c
void sort(struct node** head) {
    struct node* curr = *head;

    while (curr != NULL) {
        struct node* next = curr->next;
        while (next != NULL) {
            if(curr->val > next->val) {
                swap(&curr->val, &next->val);
                // next = next->next; 
            }
            next = next->next; // has to go here
        }
        curr = curr->next;
    }    
}
```

I acknowledge this might be confusing, but I tried to re-use the same logic as if I had to sort a vector (comparing each item as if I had an index). Thank you in advance for helping me.

EDIT: Just joking, I just noticed that I misconfigured the second `while`. The `next->next` node has to go outside the if condition

Comment: Is this a homework assignment, or would you be interested in a more efficient sort, such as [bottom up merge sort for linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists) ? If so, I can post an answer with working code.

Comment: @rcgldr It is indeed an exercise given by uni to practice, but I don't have to hand in my code or to follow any specific pattern. So, any alternative way to do this is okay for me! Thanks

Comment: Link to example of [bottom up merge sort for linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33987943/3282056) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes sense that your code won't work because you're doing bubble sort, which doesn't guarantee the list is sorted by going through a `list`, `array`, or ... once.

**To bubble sort a linked list you should write it like this:**

```
/* Bubble sort the given linked list */
void sort(node *head)
{
    /* Checking for empty list */
    if (head == NULL) return;

    int swapped;
    node *curr;
    do
    {
        swapped=0;
        curr = head;
        while (curr->next != NULL)
        {
            if (curr->val > curr->next->val)
            {
                int temp = curr->val;
                curr->val = curr->next->val;
                curr->next->val = temp;
                swapped = 1;
            }
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    } while (swapped);
}
```

Comment: The function does not sort properly. E.g. 1, 3, 2 gets sorted to 2, 1, 3. Also, it crashes if passed a pointer to an empty list.

Comment: @Jibel I would expect `prev = something;` somewhere in the `if (curr->val < prev->val)` block.

Comment: I would expect a nested loop.

Comment: @IanAbbott You are right, I fixed all the problems you mentioned. Thank you for your notice.